# Setting up 3 displays AND have an output to the TV

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, display-adapter

I have something that I am looking for an answer to.  I want to set up my computer to have 3 monitors AND have an output to my LCD TV via the HDMI port.  Can this be done with any of the ATI cards out now?  I am looking at getting an HD 5770, but am not 100% sure if this type would work or not.  I know little about the Display Port situation meaning I am not sure if an Active Adapter or a Passive Adapter will work and if it needs to be a single or dual link.  Can this type of setup be done?  Any help would be great.  I'd like to know what I am looking at BEFORE I buy anything.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found this quote reading a review:

"Last but not least, the Radeon HD 5770 keeps Eyefinity support. Like its higher-end variants in the 5000 series, you can hook up to three high resolution monitors (up to 2560x1600) to this board."

Looks like it is a yes, in that you can have three monitors. It looks like 3 connections could be the max for this card.

Comment: I was thinking of the 5770, and I have been looking at the 5850 cards.  I just need a card that will do what I would like with 3 displays AND have the option to switch to my LCD TV w/o having to switch cables around on the back of the PC.  Obviously if I want to watch a movie or play a game on the TV, I wont be having all the displays turn on at the same time.  I am hoping to find a card that will allow me to do this.

Comment: Found this via Wikipedia:
"ATI has opened the CrossFire architecture to Intel, allowing CrossFire to be enabled on many Intel chipsets which feature two x16 PCI-E slots. SLI, however, requires a motherboard which is SLI certified, which includes all nForce chipsets (such as the nForce 590 SLI, nForce 680i SLI, and nForce 790i), and most Intel X58 and Intel P55 based motherboards."
Looks like you may have to get nVIDIA cards. As I understand it, SLI is for nVIDIA cards only.

Comment: I do know that SLI = nVidia and CrossFire = ATI.  I know my computer stuff, but I just want to know all the info before deciding to buy.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a gaming card, two 3450's might be less expensive.  They each have HDMI, DVI and VGA as outputs.

DisplayPorts can be adapted to VGA, a single link HDMI or a single link DVI-I with a passive adapter.

Powered adapters usually draw power from USB, and offer dual-link outputs.

The difference between single link and dual link is the maximum resolution you get out of it.

Note: the 5770 has a full-sized DisplayPort, not a Mini.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I do not have an SLI board.  Do a Google search for "HP P6214Y" and that is my system.  I do have some games that I would like to play but need something better than the built in nVidia 9100 graphics.  I would need something where I can have 3 displays up at one time for productivity and/or gaming.  I have a separate HDMI cable running through the ceiling to my TV so I would like to switch over to the TV t play games or watch movies on it w/o having to reach behind and move cables around.

Comment: The power supply won't support a gaming video card.

Comment: Well yeah, I know that I will need to get a larger power supply as well.

Comment: It's proprietary. A standard ATX power supply won't usually work.